# Sorting in create selector

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I have a list of conversations and I want to sort them according to the updatedAt property. Is it possible to do the following when using createSelector:

```
export const getSortedConversations = createSelector(
  (state) => state.entities.chat,
  (chat) => chat.conversations.sort((a, b) => a.updatedAt - b.updatedAt)
)
```

I'm attempting to do so but when I use that selector the conversations don't get set into the state at all.

Comment: What result did you get and what do you expect?